# NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.createStrict

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am using latest versions of `JUnitParams`, `junit` and `mockito-all`.

```
testCompile group: 'pl.pragmatists', name: 'JUnitParams', version: '1.1.1'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '2.0.2-beta'
```

I keep getting `NoSuchMethodError` when running a JUnit test with annotation `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.internal.runners.RunnerFactory.createStrict(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/internal/runners/InternalRunner;

    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.<init>(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

What can be the problem that triggers `NoSuchMethodError` exception?

Code:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockTest {

    @Mock
    ServletUriComponentsBuilder servletUriComponentsBuilder;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        servletUriComponentsBuilder = mock(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGenerateUrl() {
        when(servletUriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(anyString()).build().toString())
                .thenReturn("test");

        Assert.assertEquals("my message", "test", "test");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please could you include the imports in your code?

Comment: You are using neither the newest Mockito nor the newest JUnit. Sure there is no obligation to do so, but since you explicitly state it, I need to challenge that.

Comment: This is because @Eniss is using the latest versions for the given Maven coordinates. Which is the newest JUnit 4 and the newest `mockito-all`. JUnit Jupiter has different coordinates and `mockito-all` is discontinued.

Answer (score 3):

## mockito-core

You have Mockito 1.x and 2.x on your classpath. I think that is because you have a dependency to `mockito-all:2.0.2-beta` and some of your other dependencies has a transitive dependency to `mockito-core:1.x`.

You should never use `mockito-all` with a build system that does your dependency management. Instead use

```
testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.0.2-beta'
```

or even a more current version (see [The Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.mockito%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mockito-core%22))

Mockito documentation: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Declaring-mockito-dependency

Please tell me, if this does not solve the problem.

## Creation of mocks

This is not the cause of your problem but maybe helpful, too. You are creating the `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` twice. First the `MockitoRunner` creates it because of the `@Mock` annotation and then you override it with a new mock in you `setup` method. So either you do

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MockTest {

    @Mock
    ServletUriComponentsBuilder servletUriComponentsBuilder;

    @Test
    ...
```

or you do

```
public class MockTest {

    ServletUriComponentsBuilder servletUriComponentsBuilder;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        servletUriComponentsBuilder = mock(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.class);
    }

    @Test
    ...
```

You may even do this shorter

```
public class MockTest {

    ServletUriComponentsBuilder servletUriComponentsBuilder
         = mock(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.class);

    @Test
    ...
```